# Modifying embedded hyperlink in asp.net repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I am using an asp.net `repeater` and bind data from SQL through a data table. I would like to modify the hyperlink on the client side based on the `DataRow`. There can be several other hyperlinks in the table but I have to process the one in the second column alone. What is the best way to do that? Any code sample is highly appreciated.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">ID</td>
        <td align="left">DESCRIPTION</td>
        <td >STATUS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold">Server is Down</span> 
            Click <a href="/admin.aspx">here</a> to continue.
        </td>
        <td>No Response</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? You can use a `HyperLink` control to modify the link on the serverside as well...

Comment: As I mentioned, the data is retrieved from the database. The hyperlink is actually coming from the database which needs to be modified. It is not a hyperlink control. I am trying to prefix the href with an id so that it looks something like "/2/admin.aspx".

Comment: Whatever inside <td></td> is coming from the database.

Comment: Without knowig exactly what the output can be, it's impossible to provide a solution to your problem. If it's just about getting the link in the second row of the second column, you could try some jQuery like `var links = $('#myTable tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) a');`

Comment: The output should be exactly as the input, except that the hyperlink in second column should take to "/2/admin.aspx" instead of "/admin.aspx". My application uses jQuery 1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following jQuery to change all links in the 2nd column of the 2nd row:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) a').each(function() {
        var someValue = '/2';
        $(this).prop('href', someValue + $(this).prop('href'));
    });
});
```

The issue here is where you'd get that `someValue` from. You'll have to somehow add this to the output using your `<asp:Repeater>`.
You could place it as a data attribute inside the `<td>`, something like this:

**Repeater output**

```
...
<td data-id="2">
    <span style="color: Red; font-weight: bold">Server is Down</span> 
    Click <a href="/admin.aspx">here</a> to continue.
</td>
...
```

**JS**

```
var someValue = '/' + $(this).parent().data('id');
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr. White!! It works like a charm. I used $(this).attr('href') instead of $(this).prop('href') so that I get relative urls.